# Some events added in the MultiBlocProvider doesn't get dispatched Flutter

Tags: flutter, bloc

I have added a new bloc `SyncBloc` to a `MultiBlocProvider` (`flutter_bloc` package) that creates all the blocs needed for `MapScreen` and for some it also adds Events needed to present data in the screen itself.
The problem is that while location events (for `LocationBloc`) are added correctly from the MultiBlocProvider itself, sync events (for `SyncBloc`) are not. If I instead add them from `MapScreen`'s MultiBlocListener as

```
BlocProvider.of<SyncBloc>(context).add(SyncLanguages());
```

they work as expected so looks like `SyncBloc` has been provided correctly.. Can you spot what I'm doing wrong with the newer `SyncBloc` or point me in the right direction?
As always thank you very much for your time and help.

This is the MultiBlocProvider in `main()`:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      localizationsDelegates: [
        const AppLocalizationsDelegate(),
        GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
        GlobalWidgetsLocalizations.delegate,
      ],
      supportedLocales: [
        const Locale('en', ''),
        const Locale('it', ''),
        const Locale('es', ''),
      ],
      localeResolutionCallback:
          (Locale locale, Iterable<Locale> supportedLocales) {
        for (Locale supportedLocale in supportedLocales) {
          if (supportedLocale.languageCode == locale.languageCode ||
              supportedLocale.countryCode == locale.countryCode) {
            return supportedLocale;
          }
        }
        return supportedLocales.first;
      },
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: BlocBuilder<AuthenticationBloc, AuthenticationState>(
        builder: (context, state) {
          if (state is Unauthenticated) {
            return LoginScreen(userRepository: _userRepository);
          }
          if (state is Authenticated) {
            return MultiBlocProvider(
              providers: [
                BlocProvider<TrackingBloc>(
                  create: (context) => TrackingBloc(),
                ),
                BlocProvider<DirectionsBloc>(
                  create: (context) => DirectionsBloc(),
                ),
                BlocProvider<GeoBloc>(
                  create: (context) => GeoBloc(),
                ),
                BlocProvider<RouteBloc>(
                  create: (context) => RouteBloc(),
                ),
                BlocProvider<SchedulerBloc>(
                  create: (context) => SchedulerBloc(),
                ),
                BlocProvider<CheckerBloc>(
                  create: (context) => CheckerBloc(),
                ),
                BlocProvider<LocationBloc>(
                    create: (context) => LocationBloc(
                          mapRepository: _mapRepository,
                        )
                          ..add(GetLocationStream())
                          ..add(GetLocation())
                          ..add(GetIsoLocationUser())),
                BlocProvider<SyncBloc>(
                    create: (context) =>
                        SyncBloc()..add(SyncLanguages())..add(SyncIcons())),
                BlocProvider<AlertBloc>(create: (context) {
                  return AlertBloc(
                    alertRepository: _alertRepository,
                  );
                }),
              ],
              child: MapScreen(
//                mapRepository: _mapRepository,
                user: state.user,
//              alertRepository: FirebaseAlertRepository(),
              ),
            );
          }
          return SplashScreen();
        },
      ),
      navigatorObservers: [
        FirebaseAnalyticsObserver(analytics: analytics),
      ],
    );
```

SyncEvent:

```
abstract class SyncEvent {
  const SyncEvent();

  @override
  List<Object> get props => [];
}

class SyncLanguages extends SyncEvent {}

class SyncIcons extends SyncEvent {}
```

and SyncBloc:

```
class SyncBloc extends Bloc<SyncEvent, SyncState> {
  @override
  SyncState get initialState => InitialState();

  Stream<SyncState> mapEventToState(SyncEvent event) async* {
    if (event is SyncLanguages) {
      print('SyncLanguages received');
    }
    if (event is SyncIcons) {
      print('SyncIcons received');
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by "not dispatched correctly"?
you mean you can fire the event but no state is emmited? or a wrong state is emmited?
Also are you sure you are not emmiting the same state (because bloc won't emit the state if it was the same)?

Comment: Hi for dispatch I mean `add()` like `..add(GetLocationStream())` which gets sent to `LocationBloc`, while `..add(SyncLanguages())` and `..add(SyncIcons())`are not. I know as in `SyncBloc` I print what event has arrived in `mapEventToState`.
But if I add them as `BlocProvider.of<SyncBloc>(context).add(SyncLanguages());` from  `MapScreen`'s MultiBlocListener that I do get the prints

Comment: I don't see anything weird in your code, can you provide more code (the events of SyncBloc and maybe the mapEventToState() )

Comment: sure, I also edited question and title to be more clear

Comment: I'm sure is gonna be some dumb thing that I just can't spot

Comment: can you try this please:
    BlocProvider<SyncBloc>(
    create: (context) {
      SyncBloc syncBloc = SyncBloc();
      syncBloc.add(SyncLanguages())
      syncBloc.add(SyncIcons());
      return syncBloc;
    })

Comment: Hi and thanks. I tried it, but still is not working..no SyncEvent is sent.. this is really weird

Comment: maybe file an issue on github and put an answer if you get a result

Comment: well.. Felix always asks for a sample app so before filing an issue I'd give it a few tries. Weirdly when I also add a SyncEvent from MapScrees's MultiBlocListener then also the two sent from main() are received

Comment: I did put together a sample app and filed an issue on GitHub , if you wanna fiddle with it it's https://github.com/vinnytwice/bloc_test.
In the sample app dough none of the events are sent from the second MultiBlocProvider..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem has to do with the BlocProvider's create method being lazy by default. So until the `.of` method is called BlocProvider doesn't create the bloc. To make it create the bloc immediately just set `lazy:` parameter to false.

```
BlocProvider<LocationBloc>(
                    lazy: false,
                    create: (context) => LocationBloc(
                          mapRepository: _mapRepository,
                        )
                          ..add(GetLocationStream())
                          ..add(GetLocation())
                          ..add(GetIsoLocationUser())),
                BlocProvider<SyncBloc>(
                    lazy: false,
                    create: (context) => SyncBloc()
                      ..add(SyncLanguages())
                      ..add(SyncIcons())),
```

This actually works, though AuthenticationBloc and LocationBloc events were sent even without the lazy parameter set to false. Still gotta check why that but I guess those two blocs are being created respectively by a BlocBuilder and a BlocListener. I'll edit the answer as soon as I find out for sure.